# how to show data with ajax using codeigniter

Tags: php, postgresql, codeigniter

i have tabel_item

```
id |    name    | location
1  |   item a   |   3,5 
2  |   item b   |   4
```

here I made a model

```
  public function db_barangGetMaster($postData){
    if(isset($postData['location']) ){
      $this->db->select("*");
      $this->db->from('tabel_item as a');
      $this->db->where("location", $postData['location']);
      
      $response = array();
      $query = $this->db->get()->result();
      foreach($query as $row ){
            $response[] = array(
            "id" =>$row->id,
            "name" =>$row->name,
            "lokasi" =>$row->location
        );
      }
    if (count($response)) {
        return $response;
    } else {
        return ['response' => 'not found'];
    }}
 }
```

$postData  = parameter is location

here as an example the content in the parameter is **3**
why not show?

how to display the data, if the parameter is **3** then what appears is **item a**
if the parameter is **5** then **item a**

Comment: The problem is that neither `3` and `5` will ever match `3,5`. In order to get there you probably need use `like` as in `like('location', $post['location']);`. But that only works until your locations might have 2 digits. Then you probably need to account for the `,` as well.

Comment: This is bad database design: what if there comes to an item c with location 35? What will be the result? item a, item c or both? Have a look at [Database normalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

location must be array. use `where_in` instead of `where`

```
$this->db->where_in("location", [$postData['location']]);
```

Or use

```
WHERE (location ='.$postData['location'].' 
OR location LIKE "'.$postData['location'].',%"
OR location LIKE "%,'.$postData['location'].'"
OR location LIKE "%,'.$postData['location'].',%"
)
```

Comment: not work bro ...

Comment: select * from tabel_item a where a.location in ('3') 
// I tried but can't

Comment: I edit my answer. try it

Comment: help me in query builder

Comment: just read the documentation:
https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html#looking-for-similar-data